# шестнадцатеричные номера строк vim

Tags: vim, vimrc

в vim номера строк такие:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10...
```

как сделать их такими :

```
0x1
0x2
0x3
0x4
0x5
0x6
0x7
0x8
0x9
0xA
0xB
0xC
0xD
0xE
0xF
0x10
0x11...
```

?

Comment: Видимо, нельзя https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1368

Comment: Vim -  open source. Собирается не очень сложно. Правка тоже не должна быть сложной, если мы говорим не о новой настройке а замене формата везде и всегда. Я бы попробовал.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy скажи пожалуйста, где именно изменять, я не нашёл

Comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/drawline.c#L1095

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал это! нужно просто везде

```
*fmt = "%*ld ";
```

заменить на

```
*fmt = "%*lx ";
```

в исходнике.
Или если хотите чтобы было 0xf вместо f
тогда

```
*fmt = "0x%*lx ";
```

Comment: Очень сомневаюсь, что везде.

Comment: @Qwertiy не знаю, у меня работает